# Deduct one character until a row is returned, and trim spaces when returning values [Java/SQL]

Tags: java, sql, for-loop, prepared-statement, character-trimming

i need to search string in SQL using Java, expectation is something like this:

input: `123456`

data in SQL to be fetched: `123777`

result is: `' AB C  '`

result should be: `'ABC'`

iteration will be like:

```
select col1, col2, col3 from table where input like '123456%'; --no row returned
select col1, col2, col3 from table where input like '12345%'; --no row returned
select col1, col2, col3 from table where input like '1234%'; --no row returned
select col1, col2, col3 from table where input like '123%'; --returns row for 123777
```

this is my current code:

```
public Output Method (String input) throws exception{

   Connection connection = getSQLConnection();
   String SQLquery = "SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3 FROM TABLE WHERE INPUT LIKE ?";

   if (connection != null){
      
      PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(SQLquery);
      ps.setString(1, input + "%"); 
      ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
      
      // how to deduct characters until a match is found?
      logger.debug("Executed: "+SQLquery+"; input => ["+input+"]"); 

      if(rs.next()){
         output = new Output();
         output.setOut1(rs.getString(1));
         output.setOut2(rs.getString(2));
         output.setOut2(rs.getString(3));
         //how to remove all spaces from in per result?
         //sample result: ' AB  C   ' -> should be 'ABC'

      }else{
         logger.debug("no row returned");
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: You can use `rs.getString(1).replaceAll("\\s", "")` to remove spaces. I don't really understand the problem of the other question. You just iterate over `input`, remove 1 character with each iteration till you get a result?

Comment: yes, correct. input is `123456` but available data is `123777`, it should loop by removing the last character all the time until it reaches a match in the table

Comment: You need to create a loop (probably using while) to make this happen.

Comment: for loop is preferable but i dont know how to do it

Answer (score 0):

for deduct character, this should be done:

```
for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++){
   ps.setString(1, input.substring(0, input.length()-i)); 
}
```

for trim spaces, it should be:

```
output.setOut1(rs.getString(1).replaceAll("\\s", ""));
```